# Impressão de relatórios no Firefox utilizando Telerik Reporting

Tags: firefox, telerik

Estou com um problema, que pelo visto está incomodando outros desenvolvedores que utilizam os componentes da Telerik....

http://www.telerik.com/forums/print-button-in-firefox-starts-pdf-download

E os desenvolvedores Telerik...

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/print-in-firefox

O fato é que no Firefox ele não imprime ao clicar no botão de impressão, ele pede para fazer o download ou abrir o PDF do relatório.

Alguém sabe se é possível resolver este problema? Se sim, como resolvo?

Comment: É a primeira vez que ouço falar de Telerik, mas se os desenvolvedores ainda não tem resolução oficial, acho que vai ser complicado... Lá no fórum, o admin publicou uma gambiarra, ela não atende? Tem um link também pra [esta discussão no bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=840439), viu já?

Comment: Sim, vi a gambiarra e vi a discussão no bugzilla, a gambiarra não funciona...

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Não encontrei nenhuma solução ainda, se você conhecer alguma, poste por favor. Atualmente o problema persiste, apenas foi solicitado que o usuário utilize o Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O telerik reporting não funciona em algumas versões do Firefox por usar pdf.js. Veja o ticket https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843342

Como solução de contorno mande exportar para pdf.

Obs.: acho que a nova versão do reporting e do firefox já estão ok pois antes ele não fazia nada, agora faz download do pdf ou abre o pdf no firefox, depende da configuração do firefox.

Comment: Testei com a última versão do Telerik Reporting e com a última versão do Mozila, mas ainda ele pede para salvar em PDF. Isso até que não seria um grande problema, porém os meus usuários não aceitam a ideia de ter que salvar para depois imprimir, deste modo, continuo solicitando a utilização do Google Chrome. Obrigada.

Comment: Mas é essa a solução. No melhor caso oriente os clientes a abrir o relatório usando o plugin do adobe reader configurando o firefox em Opções > Aplicativos e configurando o firefox para abrir os documentos pdf diretamente pelo firefox. Infelizmente é isso mesmo.